# Cant find GPT3.5-Turbo-16k on OpenAI Azure

Tags: azure, openai-api, gpt-3, azure-openai

I'm trying to deploy a GPT3.5-Turbo-16k model in Azure (in theory, already available, as announced by Microsoft), but i can't find it in the options, as shown in the image.

Deploying a model in Azure:

[image]

Im using East US with Standard pricing tier.
I have tried to deploy the model using Azure OpenAI Studio.
I managed to deploy the GPT3.5-Turbo model, but not the 16k version.

Answer (score 2):

> Im using East US with the Standard pricing tier. I have tried to deploy the model using Azure OpenAI Studio. I managed to deploy the GPT3.5-Turbo model, but not the 16k version.

According to this [MS-Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1329186/where-did-gpt-3-5-turbo-0613-and-gpt-3-5-turbo-16k) by AshokPeddakotla-MSFT. In the East US location, the 0613 model has been temporarily disabled due to the current investigations of customer-reported issues.

If you need to deploy a **`GPT 3.5-Turbo-16k`** model in Azure, you can use the **`UK South`** location.

I tried to deploy the **`GPT 3.5-Turbo-16k`** model in UK south location and it deployed successfully.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Model:**

[image]

**Deployment:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Introducing new and updated models to Azure OpenAI Service - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-cognitive-services-blog/introducing-new-and-updated-models-to-azure-openai-service/ba-p/3860351#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20new%20versions%20of%20gpt-35-turbo%3A,1%20gpt-35-turbo%20%28version%200613%29%202%20gpt-35-turbo-16k%20%28version%200613%29) by Derek Legenzoff.